Does Solomonoff Induction solve the Problem of Induction?
I've been reading up on Solomonoff Induction, and most of the researchers in the field seem convinced that the technique represents a solution, or at least a useful ideal, to the traditional problem of induction. How deeply has algorithmic information theory been integrated into such fields of epistemology?
Li and Vitanyi [2008, pp 347] state that, "R.J. Solomonoff's inductive method of Section 5.2, of which we have already seen a glimpse in Section 1.10, may give a rigorous and satisfactory solution to this old problem in philosophy."
Arguments have been made that support the necessity of Kolmogorov complexity in truth-tracking engines. Refer to section 8 of this paper, for example. To me, it seems that the results of algorithmic information theory are underrepresented in the epistemological literature. I'm looking for counterexamples - work from philosophers intent on fully engaging these concepts.
The original paper by Solomonoff is here for anyone interested.

Solomonoff Induction not only does not solve Hume's problem, it doesn't even address it.

@DavidGudeman you might be able to duplicate Hume's problem with it, since any physical theory needs a time domain to be meaningful, and it doesn't cost any more to encode that domain ending at the limit as t to 0 than to encode it ending at limit as t to infinity.

To solve either the problem of induction or Goodman's new riddle is to address the naivety of the uniformity of nature as already pointed out by Hume and many before. As claimed by Solomonoff himself that his induction via AIT does not explicitly use induction, but more on the razor side which could be said to solve the problem indirectly via another seemingly entirely different problem. Finally beware razor is purely metaphysical in nature wherefore observable uniformity of nature is indeed naive as QM already hints non-commutative space is much simpler than our everyday commutative space...

It's not something I can find a citation for, but I think those that see the problem of induction as a fundamental pressing issue don't consider Solomonoff induction a solution, and those who see Solomonoff induction as useful don't consider the problem of induction that important.
Like, the problem of induction is, roughly, how do you conclude from "every time I've been to the store, there have been apples there" to the universal "the store always has apples", right? And the answer Solomonoff induction would give is similar to the Bayesian answer: "Why in the world would you ever conclude with certainty that the store always has apples?". So I think Bayesian epistemology is the subfield most likely to be interested in Solomonoff induction.
And I think that people who are unconvinced by Bayesian epistemology would likely say "Why would you, a priori, believe that the universe is likely to be described by a simple Turing machine rather than a more complicated one? Because if you think that's a good model on account of your experience that in most cases, "the simplest explanation is usually best", we're right back to the problem of induction.

Within Bayesianism, there's a fundamental question of what your priors should be before you have any information. Subjectivists would say that that isn't the concern of Bayesian epistemology, and what's required is that your beliefs are coherent and update according to new evidence. Objective Bayesian epistemologists would instead say that there is a correct prior that one ought to have: uniform priors, maximum entropy priors, etc. It looks like there's definitely been some interest in Solomonoff induction as a potential solution to "how should one set priors". (Google scholar).
